# Pass Facebook application review without FB login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the app Child Rescue Ireland

I need a permission 'publish_actions' to allow users to publish posts with lost children.

So in order to use 'publish_actions' I need to pass the submission.

But FB does not allow me to do this because I need to check

```
I have tested that all platforms load and use Facebook Login.
```

But I do not use FB login, only FB sharing. How can I pass the review?

Answer (score 0):

There is NO workaround. If you want to use `publish_actions` with your app, then the users need to grant this permission to your application, which means using Facebook Login.

Furthermore, if you want to use this permission you MUST go through Login Review.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the [FB login](http://www.facebook-download.net/fb-login.php) function too in order to start using this function. Have you already contacten Facebook for this question?